# No soucers given to target error when adding sources in pybind11 and C++

Tags: c++, cmake, setuptools, pybind11

I am trying to make a library written in C++ work in python, using pybind11.

The compilation and building of the source files works without errors, but the resulting files throw this error when installing with pip.

```
 CMake Error at pybind11/tools/pybind11Tools.cmake:131 (add_library):
      Cannot find source file:

        ../project/variables.cpp

      Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm
      .hpp .hxx .in .txx
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      CMakeLists.txt:5 (pybind11_add_module)


    CMake Error at pybind11/tools/pybind11Tools.cmake:131 (add_library):
      No SOURCES given to target: project
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      CMakeLists.txt:5 (pybind11_add_module)
```

I am following the [cmake_example](https://github.com/pybind/cmake_example) and I am sure that the file exists. In fact, if I delete the file the error occur when running

```
python setup.py sdist
```

The folder structure is like this:

```
C++ project root folder
|-- C++ Project source files
|-- pybind folder
|------pybind11 source folder
|----------pybind.cpp file
|------pybind11 CmakeLists.txt
|------pybind11 Manifest.in
```

This is the CMakeLists.txt used by pybind.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(project)

add_subdirectory(pybind11)
pybind11_add_module(project
project/pybind.cpp
../project/variables.cpp
../project/instances.cpp
.
.
.
)
```

Both the C++ and the pybind source folders are included in the `Manifest.in` file. Furthermore, ther is no error refering to `project/pybind.cpp` file.

Also, this method of building the python module worked for me a couple months ago in the same project. I have tried downgradin setuptools, pybind11 and cmake but it does not work. I may be wrong, but I think the only chages I have made have been to add a couple C++ headers to the project and som functions in the `pybind.cpp`file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't use relative paths, because the location is given relative to some internal detail of CMake!

Use for instance:

```
${CMAKE_PROJECT_DIR}/project/variables.cpp
```

Or better, use the result of `FILE`, as it populates these properly.

Even `project/bind.cpp` should be relative, but you are lucky in the sense that CMake knows about that subfolder and figures it out. But don't do that, use `FILE` to select them properly (you can be relative there).

```
FILE(GLOB PYBIND_SRC
project/pybind.cpp
../project/variables.cpp
../project/instances.cpp
)

pybind11_add_module(project
${PYBIND_SRC}
)
```